# Tcl Tk to show images in Scilab

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tcl, tk-toolkit, scilab

I want to show images and videos in Scilab using a GUI made in Tcl/Tk.

Scilab has support for Tcl/Tk :- https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/section_a10b99d9dda4c3d65d29c2a48e58fd88.html.

I have made a tcl script which displays an image when run from the terminal.

```
image create photo img -file <filepath>
pack [label .mylabel]
.mylabel configure -image img
```

However when I write the following .sci file in scilab, it executes successfully but no image window is shown.

```
function sampletry()
    TCL_EvalFile(<path_to_tcl_file>);
endfunction
```

I do know that the code executed successfully because when I execute the same function again in scilab, I get an error saying that the label `.mylabel` already exists in the parent window.

Is there any way that I can show images/videos in Scilab using this method or any other method in Scilab? I'm using OpenCV to read the image and return it back to Scilab through the Scilab Api in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not servicing the event loop from your Scilab code, without which the flurry of messages from the OS to do with actually putting the window on the screen never get through and handled. Assuming you want your code to stop and wait for the viewing to be done, you can just change the Tcl/Tk code to be:

```
image create photo img -file <filepath>
if {![winfo exists .mylabel]} {
    pack [label .mylabel]
}
.mylabel configure -image img
wm deiconify .
# Wait for the user to ask for the window to be closed
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW {set done 1}
vwait done
# Process the close immediately
wm withdraw .
update
```

There's nothing very special about the `done` variable. We're just waiting for it to be set in the callback. I've added a bit of extra code to allow you to call this twice (i.e., conditionally creating the widget, ensuring that `.` is displayed and then hiding it at the end).

The simplest technique if you don't want to keep everything in the same process is to run your *original* script as a separate program, effectively doing:

```
wish <path_to_tcl_file>
```

I don't know what the easiest way to do that from Scilab is.

Comment: What if I don't wish to wait till the viewing is done? I want the control to come back to Scilab as soon as the window is displayed without waiting for it to be closed.

Comment: please help me out with this.